# Clang candidate template ignored: substitution failure (also fails to compile with gcc, VC works fine)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, clang++

I am having an issue with Clang 3.5.  The following is a self-contained repro.  This code compiles with VC12.  With Clang I get the following error:

```
1>C:\Users\jcuyle\code\branches\dev\ClientSDK\test\CompilerTestbed\CompilerTestbed.cpp(111,5): error : no matching function for call to 'out_from_storage'
1>          }( util::out_from_storage( rv ) );
1>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>  C:\Users\jcuyle\code\branches\dev\ClientSDK\test\CompilerTestbed\CompilerTestbed.cpp(37,13):  note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with storage_t = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > > &]: no matching function for call to 'out_from_storage'
1>  inline auto out_from_storage( storage_t && storage ) -> decltype( util::details::template out_from_storage( std::forward< storage_t >( storage ) ) )
1>              ^                                                     ~~~~
1>  1 error generated.
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#include <type_traits>
#include <chrono>
#include <utility>

namespace util
{
namespace details
{

template< typename RTy, typename Ty, typename enable = void >
inline RTy out_from_storage( Ty );

template< typename Ty, typename = typename std::enable_if< std::is_trivial< typename std::decay< Ty >::type >::value, Ty >::type >
inline typename std::add_pointer< typename std::decay< Ty >::type >::type out_from_storage( Ty&& t )
{
    return &t;
}

} // namespace details

template< typename storage_t >
inline auto out_from_storage( storage_t && storage ) -> decltype( util::details::out_from_storage( std::forward< storage_t >( storage ) ) )
{
    return util::details::out_from_storage( std::forward< storage_t >( storage ) );
}

} // namespace util

namespace util
{
namespace details
{

template< typename enable = void >
inline int64_t out_from_storage( std::chrono::system_clock::time_point & storage )
{
    return std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t( storage );
}

} // namespace details
} // namespace util

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point out = std::chrono::system_clock::now( );
    util::out_from_storage( out ); // error
    util::details::out_from_storage( out ); // no error

    return 0;
}
```

While this example is fairly trivial, the code is a chunk of a utility library for marshaling types across a DLL boundary.  There are a number of similar utility functions and a large number of specializations for different types.  All works fine under VC, and I suspect there's just some bogus syntax that VC accepts but needs to be slightly more correct for Clang and gcc to accept.  Significant reordering of the code is difficult, and major rewrites of the system to use a completely different approach to specializing the conversion functions (e.g. yanking out the type_traits/enable_if and using tag dispatch or similar) are impractical.  If someone can explain why it is that Clang can't find the matching function call for util::details::out_from_storage( std::chrono::system_clock::time_point & storage ) even though it pretty clearly exists (and VC can find it) I'd really appreciate it.  I'm very new to Clang and gcc.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], there's a lot of code here totally irrelevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: N.b. `util::details::template out_from_storage(` can and should be `util::details::out_from_storage(` in both places.

Comment: As a general rule, if MSVC disagrees with GCC and/or clang, MSVC is wrong.

Comment: On a practical note, you _probably_ want `std::is_trivially_copyable` rather than `std::is_trivial`.

Answer (score 3):

You have one overload of `out_from_storage` that is callable without explicitly providing template arguments, and it relies on:

```
std::is_trivial< typename std::decay< Ty >::type >::value
```

You're calling it with an instance of `time_point`, but that isn't a trivial type because it doesn't have a trivial [default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_point). Hence, this overload is removed from the set.

Since there is no viable overload, the call fails.

Comment: There are two overloads of util::details::out_from_storage, neither of which requires template arguments.  You're correct that the overload which relies on 
`std::is_trivial< typename std::decay< Ty >::type >::value` 
doesn't match because time_point isn't trivial (that's intentional), but
`template< typename enable = void >
inline auto out_from_storage( std::chrono::system_clock::time_point & storage ) -> decltype( util::details::make_out_helper( storage ) )
`
Does match, and it also doesn't require template arguments.

Comment: If I change main to:

`int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
//  auto tp = sample::time::CurrentTime( );
 std::chrono::system_clock::time_point out;
 util::details::out_from_storage( out );

 return 0;
}`

It compiles fine.  The issue is something to do with util::out_from_storage.

Comment: @JohnCuyle There are *three* overloads of `util::details::out_from_storage`. Perhaps that is your source of confusion.

Comment: In the slimmed down repro I only see two, unless you're counting the forward declaration with no implementation.  One which takes any type, provided that it meets the requirements of `enable_if`, and one which takes a `time_point`.  As the latter is an exact match and the former won't specialize, it should be the only choice.  The compiler selects the correct overload if I call `util::details::out_from_storage` but if I call `util::out_from_storage` which then calls `util::details::out_from_storage` it doesn't select the correct overload, it informs me that the incorrect one won't work.